# How to move file from on sub folder to another sub folder also repeat same for other files using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, shell, powershell-remoting

I am trying to copy a file from one location to another. The issue is there are multiples folders so am working under plugins folder which again has sub folders in it. I want to search in each folder if it contains MANIFEST.MF.eclipse file if yes, the I have to move that file in its subfolder called META-INF. (Need to do same for all subfolder under plugins)

```
$current_folder = .\temp\p2\plugins\com.xyz.*\MANIFEST.MF.eclipse -Recurse | 
$new_folder = .\temp\p2\plugins\com.xyz.*\META-INF
if (Test-Path -Path $new_folder){
 Move-Item -Path $current_folder -Destination -Path $new_folder
 }
 else{
 New-Item -ItemType 'Directory' -Name $new_folder
 Move-Item -Path $current_folder -Destination -Path $new_folder
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you're looking to search through a given directory for any files that are called "MANIFEST.MF.eclipse", then move them to a sub directory calles \META-INF?

I'm sure there's more 'elegant' solutions, but this works in my limited test

```
$rootpath = "C:\test\app"
$foldername = "META-INF"
$files = Get-ChildItem $rootpath -Recurse -Filter *MANIFEST.MF.eclipse

foreach($f in $files)
{
$testpath = $f.DirectoryName +'\'+ $foldername
    if(!(Test-Path $testpath))
    {
    mkdir $testpath
    }

Move-Item $f.FullName -Destination $testpath
}
```